# Ruby Numeric vs Integer

Tags: ruby, class

In ruby,

```
115.class => Fixnum < Integer
115.0.class => Float < Numeric
```

Can someone point of the difference between Integer class and Numeric class?
also, if I want to write some common instance function between Fixnum and Float, in which class I should write?

Comment: `Integer #⇒ Integer < Numeric`. Class inheritance chains may consist of more than one link. Answering your question: `Numeric` is the base for both `Fixnum` and `Float`. After all, what is the problem with reading docs on `Numeric` instead of immediately post the question here?

Comment: `Numeric` is quite general: it is ancestor to `Complex`, `Rational`, `Bignum`, `Float`, `Fixnum`, `Integer`, `Date::Infinity`.

Comment: In support of @mudasobwa : Learn to read some Docs: https://ruby-doc.org/core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Numeric.descendants
#=> [BigDecimal, Date::Infinity, Integer, Fixnum, Float, Bignum, Rational, Complex]
```

So if you need to define a method for both `Fixnum` and `Float` you can do it in Numeric (not talking about the  open classes monkeypatching issues)